# How to create Class.of(context) type of class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create custom class for getting custom textStyles, and i want this class to be static. But i need to pass context too for it. I've seen flutter has been using `Theme.of(context)` or `Scaffold.of(context)` methods, and i want to make same one like `CustomTextStyles.of(context).h1`. How this class should be declared ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .of method must be handcrafted for each class that uses it. It uses the InheritedWidget mechanism to walk up the context tree to find a widget of an appropriate class. See [the docs for InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html).